# Toshiba Bluetooth Stack - Evaluation Period Issues

Tags: windows, bluetooth, driver

## The Problem

I'm working on a research project and need to get the Toshiba Bluetooth Stack to work with 3rd party hardware, a long range Bluetooth receiver, in a Windows 8 environment.

It worked fine for the first month, but then I got a message stating that the "Evaluation Period" had ended. ([similar forum complaint](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/General-Troubleshooting/Bluetooh-Stack-Evaluation-Period-ends-and-can-t-figure-out-how/td-p/17479))

Does anyone have an idea as to how I can disable the flag that's causing the evaluation period message or any other way to work around the software to get this up and running?

An interesting observation is that we do use the short range Toshiba wart dongles elsewhere in the lab with the same software. It works fine for those, but gets aggressive with the third party equipment. I've had to do related research with the short-range dongles and they can *barely* work for my purposes, with a lot of workarounds

## Constraints

- Both of my research devices are Bluetooth. One's a Wii Remote, so there's lots of work arounds out there, but the other is expensive, proprietary equipment that the (small) developer only really built to work with the Toshiba Stack
- I've tried dealing with the Windows 8.1 stack, but it's highly unreliable, fussy to setup, and doesn't give me the COM port control I really need.
- I've tried contacting the manufacturer of the Bluetooth receiver, but they're some thinly supported Chinese developer and haven't responded back to me
- I've tried looking for alternatives to the Bluetooth receiver, but haven't had much luck, as most people have given up on applications involving long-range bluetooth.
- I really need to stay with my proprietary hardware provider, as they've got other, unique hardware-related specifications that are necessary.

Comment: (accidentally added as comment not solution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fantastic solution from [Mike at Closet Junk] http://mikescloset.blogspot.com/2011/12/dell-toshiba-bluetooth-350-and-windows.html

Edit the Registry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Toshiba\BluetoothStack\V1.0\Mng. Add a new DWORD key called TestVersion. Set it equal to 1.